# Change FineUploader options after initalisation

Tags: fine-uploader

Is it possible to change the FineUploader options after it has been constructed? I would like to construct the instance once, but then change the itemLimit based on the circumstances. So I would construct the instance like this:

```
App.fineUploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({ itemLimit: 25 });
```

And then change the itemLimit at some point:

```
App.fineUploader.setOption('itemLimit', 10);
```

I can't seem to find a function like that in the docs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

I think thats not possible on the current version, however you can try overriding the limit as a workaround, here is an example (JS):

```
$("#uploader").fineUploader()
    .on("validate", function() {
        if (itemLimitOverride > 0) {
            return itemLimitOverride > $(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads");
        }
    });
```

An you set **itemLimitOverride** to an non 0 value in-scope.

Check this thread: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/999

Comment: Your example is for the jQuery version, while my question is about the FineUpload Basic so I can't accept your answer. But thanks for pointing this out and the link to the Github issue!